# Find the least positive integer $n$ such $S(n^2)+7=S(n)$

Tags: contest-math, decimal-expansion

This is contest math problem:

> For a positive integer $N=\overline{a_{n}a_{n-1}\cdots a_{0}}$ in decimal representation we denote by $S(N)$ the sum of its digits $a_{0}+a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}+a_{n}$. then find the minimal $n$ such
>   $$S(n^2)=S(n)-7$$

Comment: Note that $S(n) \equiv n \mod 9$, which reduces our search space, because this implies that
$$
n^2\equiv S(n^2) = S(n) - 7 \equiv n-7 \pmod 9
$$
and the solutions to $n^2 \equiv n - 7\pmod 9$ are $2, 5, 8$, or $n\equiv 2 \pmod 3$. That means that you need only to to search among $\{2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Thanks,But I  can't find the $n_{min}$ such it in for $3k-1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well known that
$$S(n)\equiv n\pmod 9$$

Then, the equation implies: 
$$n^2\equiv n-7\pmod9$$
Note that this implication is not reversible, so we will need to check the solutions we can find.
The latter equation can be written so:
$$n^2-10n+25\equiv 0\pmod 9$$

So $(n-5)^2\equiv 0\pmod 9$. Therefore,
$$n-5\equiv 0\pmod 3$$
So $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$.

On the other hand, note that
$$S(n)=S(n^2)+7\ge 9$$
and since $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$, $S(n)\ge 11$.

Trying a bit yields the solution: $149$.

Comment: Could you be explicit about how much help it is to know that $n\equiv2$ mod $3$ and $S(n)\ge11$?  In particular, how many numbers did you need to square (and sum the digits) before you settled on $n=149$?

Comment: All the numbers $n$ such that $S(n)\in\{11,14,17\}$. From $29$ to$149$ there are $20$, if I have not miscounted.

Answer (score -2):

149
179
389
449
548
749
899

And many others

java code:

```
public class PrecalcMS {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LongStream.range(0, 100000).parallel().filter(x->digitsum(x)-digitsum(x*x)==7).forEach(x->System.out.println(x));
}

private static int digitsum(long x) {
    final String pres = ""+x;
    return IntStream.range(0, pres.length()).map(i->pres.charAt(i)-'0').sum();
}
```

}

Comment: I think that this problem is not meant to be solved like this. I feel this like: "Hey, guys, I have beaten the World Record of the Marathon. It's easy going by car".